# how to make jquery menu be closed by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I`m new to JS, so I`m sorry for such easy question. I have slide up/down menu, I want it to be closed by default when the page loads and open when clicking. How can I do this? Thanks very much for the responses. Here is the code:

```
$('.button-show').click(function() {                             

    if ($(this).hasClass('hidden-menu')) {

        $(this).next().slideDown(300);

        $(this).removeClass('hidden-menu');

    } else {
       $(this).next().slideUp(300);

       $(this).addClass('hidden-menu');
    }

    return false;
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the class 'hidden menu' to the menu in your html file?

Comment: Does your menu has `hidden-menu` class? Looks like that class makes your menu keep hidden.

Comment: You did not specify what is the class or HTML of the menu you are talking about, you only specified the `button` that toggles that menu.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `.hidden-menu` class on the menu when the page loads. You can add it directly to the html so that it is hidden without any javascript having to run:

```
<div class="menu hidden-menu">
```

Or you can use some javascript after the DOM has loaded, which is similar to what you have now just somewhere outside of the click handler:

```
$(".menu").addClass("hidden-menu")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `.ready()` function to set the `hidden-menu` class by default:

```
// when your page finished loading
$(document).ready(function () {
   // check if there is no .hidden-menu class
   if (!$(".MENUCLASS").hasClass("hidden-menu")
   {
       // then add it
       $(".MENUCLASS").addClass("hidden-menu");
   }
});
```

or just simply put it in your HTML element, no hassle:

```
<div class="MENUCLASS hidden-menu">
   // stuff
</div>
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

on page load you just add inline css display:none;

you problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to hide your div by default using CSS and apply jQuery see below code

```
$('.button-show').click(function() { 
 jQuery('.menu').slideToggle();
 jQuery(this).toogleClass();
});
```